# I can't get my static class working with a Generic List

Tags: asp.net

I have a static class that needs to pass a generic List of strings to a function using an integer as a index to the List in the class. The problem is the static class doesn't have a List collect and I don't have a proper index to access the class in the function it is passed to. The class, the calling code, and the receiving function are below.

My Class:

```
public class QueryContainer
{
    public static QueryContainer Instance = new QueryContainer();
    private int _id;
    private string _query = "";
    private int _searchID;

    public QueryContainer() { }

    public string Query
    {
        get
        {
            if (Instance != null)
                return Instance._query;
            else
                return "";
        }
        set { _query = value; _id =+ 1; }
    }

    public int ID { get { return _id; } }

    public int SearchID
    {
        set { _searchID = value; }
        get { return _searchID; }
    }        
}
```

The calling code:

```
public int GetAccountSortByAccountCode(int account)
{
    int Id = 0;
    QueryContainer.Instance.Query = "SELECT ac_sort_order FROM lkup_account_codes where ac_code = " + account.ToString();
    return Convert.ToInt32(ExecuteScaler(Id));
}
```

The function that the static class is passed to:

```
public int GetAccountSortByAccountCode(int account)
{
    int Id = 0;
    QueryContainer.Instance.Query = "SELECT ac_sort_order FROM lkup_account_codes where ac_code = " + account.ToString();
    return Convert.ToInt32(ExecuteScaler(Id));
}
```

The Function

```
    protected Object ExecuteScaler(int ID)
    {
        object returnValue = null;

        if (!_iserror)
        {
            if (_trace)
            { DoTrace("TAMIS.Data.Loader.ExecuteScalar", QueryContainer.Instance.Query); }

            if (_connection == null || _connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                OpenConnection();
            }

            DbCommand command = _provider.CreateCommand();
            command.Connection = _connection;
            {
                command.CommandText = QueryContainer.Instance.Query;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                if (_useTransaction) { command.Transaction = _transaction; }

                try
                {
                    returnValue = command.ExecuteScalar();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex is EntryPointNotFoundException)
                        throw ex;
                    //if (_useTransaction == true)
                    //_transaction.Rollback();
                    RollBack();

                    LogBLL bll = new LogBLL();
                    bll.WriteErrorLog(ex);

                    _iserror = true;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if ((!KeepAlive && _connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) || _iserror == true)
                    {
                        CloseConnection();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue = -1;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using QueryContainer as a [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx#cctor).

In ASP.Net, you receives multiple requests from different users. It is not a good way to construct dynamic query.

Basically, what you are doing is all requests will use same QueryContainer instance. I don't think it is what you want.

The bottom line is do not use static in your scenario.

Comment: Below is the best I could come up with. Now the SQL injection error was showing up in the actual ExecuteScaler function using the SQL string being passed in as so:

 The old version my code replaced: protected object ExecuteScaler(string queryString)

 Now my version of the function is as so: protected Object ExecuteScaler(QueryContainer Instance)

 The calling function is now converted as so: